# Is this character dead in Supernatural?

Tags: supernatural

At the end of Season 10,

> Dean *appears* to kill Death

The question I have is:

> How can Death be dead if the Reapers are still active? Do we have any evidence pointing to the possibility that Death is just yanking the brothers' collective chains?

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to suspect he's alive, but if watching him die on screen wasn't proof enough that's he's gone, I suppose it's anyone's guess.  As for why the Reapers are still active - I don't recall anything suggesting they would cease to exist or be incapable of operating without Death himself around to manage them.

Comment: Just to add to OP's point, he had a conversation with Dean when they first met that implied he couldn't be killed

Comment: He implied that he would outlive God, but that doesn't _necessarily_ mean he couldn't be killed, only that he never expected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes, Death is dead...

But, it turns out that 'Death' is simply a 'title' for the 'head' reaper.

Once the current death dies, the *next* reaper to die is 'promoted' to the top spot and 'becomes' death.

When the 'original' death ([Julian Richings](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0724995/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t55)) is killed by Dean, it is later revealed that Billie ([Lisa Berry](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2484864/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t15)) has become death.

In the penultimate episode, Lucifer returns to the bunker with a reaper who he quickly kills. She is then 'promoted' to become death and comes back to 'life' thus proving how the succession works.

Answer (score 4):

We actually don't know. Everything we see through Season 12 so far strongly suggests that he is, but as it's *Supernatural*, anything can happen.

The major piece of evidence we have that Death is really done comes from the Reapers themselves. In one season 11 episode ("In Form and Void"), they run into the Reaper Billie. She explains that with Death gone, Sam and Dean will no longer get any chances for resurrection. She claims that Death used to find it "amusing" that the two kept coming back to life, but the Reapers are pissed at them for killing their boss, so the next time they die it's permanent.

It's also notable that, when he died, Death's scythe crumbled to dust.

---

On the other hand, the actor who played Death (Julian Richings) has *supposedly* claimed at a fan convention that Death was planned to return in Season 12. As far as I know, that did not happen, but the show was renewed for a Season 13, so who knows. I will also point out that, at one point, Reaper Billie mentions something about "old Death" and "new Death", so if Death does return it may be a different character; perhaps another being "ascends" to take Death's place. At this point, that's all speculative.